# JSF 2.X Passing parameter between two xhtml pages

Tags: jsf

I am trying to pass parameter between two pages.my **User.xhtml** page has  **ui:repeat** which displays user.I have access to the **user  Id** as well.  I want to click on the user and go to their details page. I have **userDetails.xhtml** which is blank at the moment.

I have a Bean as well.

Currently I am using **h:link** to navigate one page to another. And it works.

My mission is : Click on the user and get their details.

Please help, I am pretty new in JSF

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can try using `<f:param>`:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{userBean.users}" var="u">
    ...
    <h:link outcome="userDetails" value="Details">
        <f:param name="userID" value="#{u.id}" />
    </h:link>
    ...
</ui:repeat>
```

then you can get the id like this:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class UserDetailsBean {

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.userID}")
    private String userID;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

Comment: I guess I need getters and setters yes ?